# How to add Span to figure legend in bokeh?

Tags: bokeh, legend

So I create a figure with some lines and a span (or multiple spans).

```py
f = figure()
f.line(x, y1, legend_label='1st set')
f.line(x, y2, legend_label='2st set')
vl = Span(location=x_point,
          dimension='height',
          line_dash='dotdash', line_color="black", line_alpha=0.7)
f.add_layout(vl)
```

I would like to add span entry to the default legend of the figure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `Legend` works only with glyph renderers, so you cannot directly add `Span` to a legend.

But you can create a glyph with no data and with the same parameters as the span:

```py
f.line([], [], legend_label='span',
       line_dash='dotdash', line_color="black", line_alpha=0.7)
```

Comment: Hi, this some not seem to work (anymore) with bokeh 2.3.1. If I use an empty line, I will get the legend name but without the corresponding line close to it.

Comment: Looks like a bug, I created https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/11193