# How to add Span to figure legend in bokeh>=2.4?

Tags: python, bokeh

In a bokeh plot, I want to add an entry to the legend that represents a Span.

The following approach does not work:

```py
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Span
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

data = {'y1': [1, 2, 3, 2, 1],
        'y2': [2, 3, 2, 3, 2],
        'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
source = ColumnDataSource(data=data)
colors = ['red', 'yellow']

# Create figure
p = figure(width=400, height=400)

bars = p.vbar_stack(['y1', 'y2'], x='x', source=source, color=colors,
                    legend_label=['y1', 'y2'])

# Add a Span
span = Span(location=2, dimension='width', line_dash='dashed',
             line_color="green", line_width=2)
p.add_layout(span)

# Add a line glyph with no data to represent the Span in the legend
p.line([], [], legend_label='Span', line_dash='dashed', line_color="green", line_width=2)
# This used to be a solution, but does not work anymore with bokeh>=2.4

show(p)  # Show plot
```

[image]

Adding data points to the additonal line makes it show up in the legend, but well, then I have an additional line in the plot. I can set its attribute `visible` to False, but even then it is still part of the plot. The default zoom will try to keep it in the frame. My frame however changes because I am switching out the x-axis, so that is annoying.
That is also why until now I have avoided to contruct the span itself as a line: I would have to recalculate its position on every axis update.

I am aware that this is an exact duplicate of [How to add Span to figure legend in bokeh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60829090/how-to-add-span-to-figure-legend-in-bokeh)
But that question received an answer which is no longer valid with later version of bokeh (ask discussed in the comments there).
From this [Should you re-ask a question if it's been asked but the answer hasn't worked for you?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346177/should-you-re-ask-a-question-if-its-been-asked-but-the-answer-hasnt-worked-for?noredirect=1&lq=1) i gather that it is ok to ask the question again.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I received the answer over on the [bokeh discourse](https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/how-to-add-span-to-figure-legend/10512/2), but I wanted to save it here, as well.
Currently we have to work with a fake line glyph to add something to the legend, but we can properly hide it from the plot itself:

- Disable the visibility
- Make sure the auto-range does not include the fake line

```py
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Span
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

data = {'y1': [1, 2, 3, 2, 1],
        'y2': [2, 3, 2, 3, 2],
        'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
source = ColumnDataSource(data=data)
colors = ['red', 'yellow']

# Create figure
p = figure(width=400, height=400)

bars = p.vbar_stack(['y1', 'y2'], x='x', source=source, color=colors,
                    legend_label=['y1', 'y2'])

# Add a Span
span = Span(location=2, dimension='width', line_dash='dashed',
            line_color="green", line_width=2)
p.add_layout(span)

# Add a line glyph with minimal data to represent the Span in the legend
r_line = p.line([0], [0], legend_label='Span', line_dash='dashed',
                line_color="green", line_width=2)
r_line.visible = False  # Set this fake line to invisible

# The auto-range would still include this invisible object.
# But we have two options to deal with that.

# a) exclude invisible renderers from automatic bounds computations
p.x_range.only_visible = True
p.y_range.only_visible = True

# b) Specifically set the renderers to autorange against
# p.x_range.renderers = bars
# p.y_range.renderers = bars

show(p)  # Show plot
```

[image: Figurewith glyph]